# Геолокация в C#

Tags: c#, wpf, геолокация

Какие есть способы получить долготу и широту устройства в C#? Я пробовал с помощью `GeoCoordinateWatcher`, но тщетно. Делал всё как по книжке, но в итоге функция `GetGeolocation` возвращает мне объект `Geolocation` с нулевыми `Latitude` и `Longtitude`.

```
public class Geolocation
{
    public static Geolocation GetGeolocation()
    {
        Geolocation res = new Geolocation();

        GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher();

        watcher.TryStart(false, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

        if (!watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown)
        {
            res.Latitude = watcher.Position.Location.Latitude;
            res.Longtitude = watcher.Position.Location.Longitude;
        }

        return res;
    }

    public double Latitude      { get; private set; }
    public double Longtitude    { get; private set; }
}
```

Вот теперь может вы мне подскажите что я делаю не так, или же альтернативные способы получить геоданные?

Comment: Само-собой я понимаю, что по каким-то причинам у меня `watcher.Position.Location.IsUnknown` - `true`, вот только по каким именно причинам...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваш код работает, просто ему не хватает времени для определения локации.

Я скопировал ваш код, добавил вот такой вызов

```
        bool exit = false;
        int count = 0;
        while (!exit)
        {
            var loc = Geolocation.GetGeolocation();
            if (loc.Latitude>0)
            {
                exit = true;
            }
            count++;
        }
```

Иногда срабатывает с первого раза, иногда с 6-9. Попробуйте увеличить таймаут. При увеличении его до 10000 мс срабатывает с первого раза. У меня.